# How can I initialize Gradle projects in non-English systems?

Tags: java, windows, powershell, gradle

I am trying to use Gradle on my Windows machine. The command I want to be able to use is:

```
gradle init --type java-application
```

But here is the error I get when I run this command on Powershell (or cmd):

```
> Task :init FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':init'.
> The requested build type 'java-application' is not supported. Supported types:
- 'basic'
- 'cpp-application'
- 'cpp-library'
- 'groovy-appl²cat²on'
- 'groovy-gradle-plugin'
- 'groovy-l²brary'
- 'java-appl²cat²on'
- 'java-gradle-plugin'
- 'java-l²brary'
- 'kotlin-appl²cat²on'
- 'kotlin-gradle-plugin'
- 'kotlin-l²brary'
- 'pom'
- 'scala-appl²cat²on'
- 'scala-l²brary'
- 'swift-application'
- 'swift-library'
```

As seen in the output, there is probably an encoding issue here. Because

```
java-appl²cat²on
```

is displayed as a possible type.
I used versions 6.9 and 7.0.2 and the results are the same. My system language is Turkish but I also use Git, Maven etc. without any issues.

Here is the output of `gradle --version` in case it is useful:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 6.9
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2021-05-07 07:28:53 UTC
Revision:     afe2e24ababc7b0213ccffff44970aa18035fc0e

Kotlin:       1.4.20
Groovy:       2.5.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.9 compiled on September 27 2020
JVM:          1.8.0_231 (Oracle Corporation 25.231-b11)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64
```

Comment: I know that Turkish language has two 'i' characters: one with a dot on top, and one without. When you are using international tools, you always need to type the 'i' character with the dot on top of it.

Comment: @Dominique I know. You can see the command `gradle init --type java-application`, it does not have any ı

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: Issue [`#17383`](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/17383) has been fixed and is targeted for Gradle 7.2.

You may hit a bug in Gradle. I was able to reproduce the issue by forcing `tr-TR` locale in environment variable `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS`. I filed a bug in the Gradle issue tracker to have this checked: [Build init plugin is locale sensitive](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/17383).

As a workaround, you could force English locale for project initialization, in Powershell:

```
PS> $env:JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US"
PS> gradle.bat init --type java-application
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US

Select build script DSL:
  1: Groovy
  2: Kotlin
Enter selection (default: Groovy) [1..2]
```

Comment: Well, I was able to bypass this problem by changing my system language to English. But I think your suggestion might be a better way. Thanks.